# Multiple File Upload in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to upload multiple file to the server by my iPhone. The problem is that when I try to upload 1.4 mb file it could not upload properly. I checked the uploaded file and the file size is 1 kb. So I made this code based on the postman. As you know the postman can create the code according to which language do you want. Thank you.

```
  function uploadFile(){

var parameters: [[String: Any]] = []
var fileCount: Int = 0
 
let homeDirectory = ""
var soundPath = "\(homeDirectory)\(CommonUtil.PATH_SOUND)"
soundPath = soundPath.replacingOccurrences(of: "file:///", with: "")

//fiels[0] = ["fileName" : "2021_10_19_09_12_52.wav"]
//fiels[1] = ["fileName" : "2021_10_19_09_12_53.wav"]
//fiels[3] = ["fileName" : "2021_10_19_09_12_54.wav"]
for item in files{
    var dict = item as! [String:String]
                                
    let strFilePath = "\(soundPath)\(dict["fileName"]!)"
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: strFilePath){
        var dict = [String:Any]()
        dict.updateValue("strFileName[\(fileCount)]", forKey: "key")
        dict.updateValue(strFilePath, forKey: "src")
        dict.updateValue("file", forKey: "type")
                                    
        parameters.append(dict)
        fileCount++
      }
                                
      print(dict["fileName"]!)
}

var dict = [String:Any]()
dict.updateValue("strApiName", forKey: "key")
dict.updateValue("soundFileUpload", forKey: "value")
dict.updateValue("text", forKey: "type")
                
parameters.append(dict)    
uploadFiles(parameters: parameters)
}

func uploadFiles(parameters: [[String: Any]]){
    
    var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    
    let boundary = "Boundary - \(UUID().uuidString)"
    var body = ""
    var error: Error? = nil
    
    for param in parameters {
      if param["disabled"] == nil {
        let paramName = param["key"]!
        body += "--\(boundary)\r\n"
        body += "Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"\(paramName)\""
        if param["contentType"] != nil {
          body += "\r\nContent-Type: \(param["contentType"] as! String)"
        }
        let paramType = param["type"] as! String
        if paramType == "text" {
          let paramValue = param["value"] as! String
          body += "\r\n\r\n\(paramValue)\r\n"
        } else {
            let paramSrc = param["src"] as! String
            //let fileData = URL(string: paramSrc)?.dataRepresentation ?? Data()
            let fileData = try! NSData(contentsOfFile:paramSrc, options:[]) as Data
            let fileContent = String(data: fileData, encoding: .utf8)
            body += "; filename=\"\("file:///"+paramSrc)\"\r\n"
                 + "Content-Type: \"content-type header\"\r\n\r\n\(fileContent)\r\n"
        }
      }
    }
    
    body += "--\(boundary)--\r\n";
    let postData = body.data(using: .utf8)

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://api.polytus.com/")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
     
    request.addValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = postData

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
      guard let data = data else {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.showLoading(show: false)
          self.showBluetoothAlert(message: "failed")
        }
        
        print(String(describing: error))
        semaphore.signal()
        return
      }
        
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.showLoading(show: false)
        self.showBluetoothAlert(message: "success")
      }
        
      print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
      semaphore.signal()
    }
    
     
    task.resume()
    semaphore.wait()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what I've understand you want to know the file size in the server filesystem. If this is you want you have to use an API that give you back the data, after the file is uploaded and moved from temporary web server space to final location. In brief you need to do 2 request, one for upload and one for getting the file data (space or any other data needed), or develop an API that give you as answer of the correct upload the file size.

Comment: Hello Massimo Pavanel. Thank you for answer and I edited my question could you check please.

Comment: Sincerely I use Alamofire framework for these things, it's easier and less work overall. But, seems for what you say that, the problem is on the server side. When you upload, and you got the problem, what is the response of the API or the web server?